# Is there an advantage for a completely dynamic mobile site opposed to having some pages at separate mobile URLs and some pages dynamic?

Tags: seo, url, mobile, dynamic

We are serving both mobile and desktop platforms through a single domain. In case of mobile, we append /m at end of the domain.

In some cases, pages are served dynamically. Common URL for both the platforms but the different content is served through device detection.

1. Is it fine if we continue following current(hybrid) approach?
2. Would it give us any SEO advantage if we start serving content dynamically across the site?

Comment: Is there any reason that you are not considering responsive web design?   Google says that dynamic, separate URLs, or responsive are all fine for SEO, but there are big advantages to responsive in terms of ease of development and a single code base.  See https://developers.google.com/search/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/

Comment: We have different design strategies for mobile and desktop! We are a high traffic website. Performance is also a concern for us.